# Fortran Syntax Highlighting detecting apostrophes as Strings

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, filetype-fortran

I am using VIM 7.4 with syntax highlighting on some Fortran77 source code.  One comment has a single apostrophe that never is repeated/closed (eg * Bert's bees), causing the remaining source code to be highlighted as a string.

```
! comment ignores apostrophe's as string
c A comment where apostrophe's are considered strings
* This comment is displaying fully as a string
C Comment with the closing apostrophe, it's not great

PROGRAM myexample

END PROGRAM
```

My .vimrc has been cleaned to only contain :syntax on and my .vim folder has been deleted.  This is what I am seeing in Putty:

[image]

I would assume the problem is the default fortran.vim file isn't correctly grabbing the comment labels for c, C, and d, but is working for ! comments (where it correctly ignores the apostrophe).

Comment: What Vim version is this?

Comment: Standard Fortran plugin does not seem to recognize strings embedded in comments. You probably have some local plugins/modifications.

Comment: @Matt I have been able to reproduce the issue by only using the following in the .vimrc document:

filetype plugin indent on
:syntax on       

I guess I will remove this and see if things are better.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is also in the latest Vim. It seems comments in the form of `c text` and `* text` are not recognized at all, only `! text` comments are.

Looking at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/fortran.vim` it loos like it modifies the syntax highlighting behaviour to match various Fortran dialects. `:help ft-fortran-syntax` has some more details on this.

Adding `let g:fortran_fixed_source = 1` to my vimrc seems to fix the comment problem for me, although it now gives errors on the `PROGRAM` and `END` lines, which are  "left margin errors" according to the comment in the syntax file. I'm not familiar with Fortran at all, but it seems to require numbers and/or indentation before the actual code. `let g:fortran_have_tabs = 1` can be used to disable that, if you want.